# Is there a way to control how git highlights differences?

Tags: git, git-diff

```
$ git diff -b -w --ignore-blank-lines --color-words="[^[:space:]]|([[:alnum:]]|UTF_8_GUARD)+" .../dbupgrade.sh
diff --git a/.../dbupgrade.sh b/.../dbupgrade.sh
index e2d2803b..b738bb64 100755
--- a/.../dbupgrade.sh
+++ b/.../dbupgrade.sh
@@ -131,7 +131,7 @@ if [[ "${success}" == "yes" ]]; then

    echo "Upgrade was successful. Rebuild 'prtl' tool and redeploy cluster services from your local hos>
    echo "  rm -rf derived-src/services"
    echo "  ../prtl dev static-files-copy -f;../prtl build all --skip-docker-test -v"
    echo "  ../prtl deploy wi-stop; ../prtl deploy stop; ../prtl deploy start; ../prtl deploy wi-start"
else
    # Do not run containers with changed configuration
```

I want that git highlights `../prtl` at the beginning of string, instead of the end:

[image]

Comment: Yes, there is a  way: https://git-scm.com/docs/diff-options/2.6.7#Documentation/diff-options.txt---diff-algorithmpatienceminimalhistogrammyers I don't know if you can achieve the result you want.